# Sql query to keep "counted" the rows that have been deleted

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a classified site... I'm trying to make a sql query that COUNTS the number of ads the user has posted in last 7 days, but I have a problem...

I'm trying to show in user profile something like this for example: *[Username] has posted 30 ads in last 7 days*

Here is my sql query ->

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table_name 
WHERE user_id = '[user_id]' AND created_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

So in my case "table_name" contains ALL the ads from all the users and by "`user_id` = '[user_id]'" I show the user A his number of ads, and to USER B his number of ads etc...

So this query works, it counts the number of ads correctly, BUT, if for example user enters on site and DELETE's 1,2 or whatever number of his ads, this number will be "minused" from the "[Username] has posted 30 ads in last 7 days"

1. So let's say for example user posted 20 ads in the last 5 days - The correct result is *[Username] has posted 20 ads in last 7 days*
2. Now user enters on site and delete's 4 ads - Now the result is *[Username] has posted 16 ads in last 7 days*

Can somebody help me please, what can I add to the query so the count still shows the correct number of ads (in my case 20 ads), even if the ads where deleted..

Thank you
Cheers

Comment: If you delete all trace of deleted adds from the database, there's no way a SQL query can know about them.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. Yes I was thinking about this too... I will have a think about what and how to do. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of deleting a row using a `DELETE ... WHERE ...` statement, add a `deleted` column and use an `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE ... SET deleted = 1 WHERE ...
```

Then your counting function will work without modification.

Of course you will now have to fix all the rest of your code to not show deleted adverts. You can do this by adding `WHERE NOT deleted` to all your other queries. You could also create a view that only shows ads that are not deleted and update your code to query this view instead of the original table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you think it's good to STILL keep all the ads in the table (as the table will be heavier and heavier), or maybe should I just "leave" this "feature" about the last 7 days..? Thanks

Comment: @Vzlotea: Keep them. Unless you are expecting hundreds of millions of adverts in your system, it's unlikely you'll ever need to delete any data for performance reasons (there may be legal reasons for permanently deleting data though). If you are worried about performance then make sure you understand how **indexes** work. A missing index is a common reason for a query running too slowly. If you do run into performance issues, you can (for example) delete rows marked as deleted that are more than one year old.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I will make "deleted" column and use your advice in reading more and improving indexes.. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than deleting the ads from the system, add a "deleted" flag, or move them to a deleted table. This way you never lose the record of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you think it's good to STILL keep all the ads in the table (as the table will be heavier and heavier), or maybe should I just "leave" this "feature" about the last 7 days..? Thanks

Comment: As Mark pointed out, I definitely suggest keeping them. Databases are good at searching through data using indexes. If the table ever becomes a problem, then you can segment the database based on age. This will provide you the added benefit of being able to run various analytical queries against your database to figure out who needs prodding to push more ads, or maybe even more relevant ads. Ultimately, it just gives you a lot more flexibility to keep them.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing you can add to a query to find data which has been deleted. You need *not* to delete the data, but add a marker to the record the user wants to delete to *indicate* that it's been removed from display.

As well as allowing the record to be counted, it has the **additional advantage** that the user can be permitted to reinstate that advert, if he wants to.